# Maintain hreflang external pages in typo3

Tags: typo3, hreflang

I would like to **maintain** the hreflang for pages in Typo3 7.6.19.
This is not possible automatically, because the pages are external and different.

With Yoast-SEO this possibility (at least in my version) does not come along.
It is an old Typo3 version, so I cannot use the extension `bgm_hreflang` from the TER.

Anyone an idea?

*The structure of the hreflang meta is known.*
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/localized-versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out. I checked at which position the hreflang was generated:

```
headerData {

    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1
        special.normalWhenNoLanguage = 0
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
                stdWrap.cObject {
                    value = de || en
                }
                linkWrap = <link rel="alternate" hreflang="|
                doNotLinkIt = 1
                after.cObject = TEXT
                after.cObject {
                    stdWrap {
                        wrap = " href="|" />
                        typolink {
                            parameter.data = TSFE:id
                            #page:uid
                            additionalParams = &L=0 || &L=1
                            returnLast = url
                            forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                            addQueryString = 1
                            addQueryString.method = GET
                            addQueryString.exclude = gclid,L,id,cHash,no_cache,backPid
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            CUR = 1
            CUR.doNotShowLink = 1

            # No Translation
            USERDEF1 = 1
            USERDEF1.doNotShowLink = 1

            USERDEF2 < .CUR
        }
    }
 }
```

And then overwritten by the template extension per page:

```
page.headerData.10 >
page.headerData.10 = TEXT
page.headerData.10.value (
(...)
<link rel="alternate" href="https://example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
)
```

Of course, it would be nicer if the editor would only have to enter urls as HTML code, but for the moment it fits.